# TYPO3: typoscript wrap two elements with div

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

is it possible to wrap always two `<li>` elements in a div in typoscript?

at the moment it looks like this:

```
navStatic = HMENU
navStatic {
    special = directory
    special.value = 2
    excludeUidList = 2
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul class="headernavmenu">|</ul>
        noBlur = 1

        NO = 1
        NO {
            ATagTitle.field = title
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            allWrap =   |  I  |*| |  I  |*| |
        }

        ACT < .NO
        ACT.ATagParams = class="active_static"
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: wrapping `<li>` with `<div>`? bad idea as that would result in invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This addition to your TypoScript should do the job, just when an odd number of `li`-elements is in the list the last single `li`-element is not wrapped.

```
NO.wrapItemAndSub.outerWrap =   <div class="two-list-elements">  || ||  </div>
```

Be advised that this HTML-solution is error-prone as browsers might interpret it different or not at all because the HTML is not standard-conform.